# Help understanding existence proof for the set of countable ordinals?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers, ordinals

I am currently studying Real Analysis by Folland and in a section on well-ordering he gives the following proof:

[Proof of existence of countable set of ordinals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54LF7.png)

Essentially the proof proceeds as follows:
We want to find an uncountable, well-ordered set $Q$ such that for each $q\in Q$, $I_q$ is countable.
Here $I_q = \{p \in Q \mid p < q\}$ (i.e. the predecessors of $q$ in $Q$ wrt the well-ordering on $Q$)

1. There exist uncountable well-ordered sets by the well-ordering principle
2. Choose such a set, $X$. If $X$ has the property we are done.
3. Otherwise, there is a minimal $x_0$ such that $I_{x_0}$ is uncountable, in which case $Q = I_{x_0}$

I am confused by step 3, if the set of predecessors of $x_0$ is uncountable how can the set of predecessors for any element of this set be countable? If I choose any element in $I_{x_0}$, it should have uncountably many predecessors right? Hence this set doesn't actually have the property we want?

I'm also quite confused at what it means to find a minimal element of an uncountable set. For instance if we consider the reals, $\mathbb R$, this is an uncountable set <s>with a natural well-ordering</s>, but it does not seem obvious to me that the notion of a "minimal" element makes any sense here, especially given that for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$, $I_x$ should be uncountable. (My logic here is that one can show an injection from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$, hence any other bounded range I choose can be mapped to $\mathbb R$ as well and is therefore uncountable).

Comment: Reread the definition of well-ordering, the natural ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ is not a well-ordering. "If I choose any element in $I_{x_{0}}$, it should have uncountably many predecessors right?" Then $x_{0}$ wouldn't be minimal with the property of $I_{x_{0}}$ being uncountable.

Comment: It might help to first consider the *first infinite ordinal* $\omega$: it has infinitely many predecessors, but each ordinal $\alpha<\omega$ has only finitely many predecessors. The situation is analogous with respect to the *first uncountable ordinal* $\omega_1$, which is what this question is about even if that notation hasn't been  introduced in the book.

Comment: @FZan I see now that because the notion of a minimal element is problematic in R that it is not well-ordered but totally ordered. But I'm still confused as to how we can hope to find a minimal element in I_x0 when I_x0 is uncountable - similarly to R. My question is essentially the same, how can I choose a set that has uncountably many elements but ensure that each element has countably many predecessors?

Comment: Your first assumption was assuming there was a well-ordering through the well-ordering principle. "how can I choose a set that has uncountably many elements but ensure that each element has countably many predecessors?" That's the magic of the well-ordering principle/axiom of choice.

Comment: @FZan The most confusing part of this idea for me is that it essentially implies that if I have an uncountably infinite set of elements that is well-ordered, then if I take the set of predecessors of the maximal element, x_max, the set of predecessors I_xmax is countable. Essentially, if I take an uncountable, well-ordered set and I remove one element from the end now I've produced a countable set? That doesn't seem to make sense to me - I'm sure I'm missing something but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @Arham No, it doesn't imply any of this, you are doing something else entirely here. In the proof you are taking the **minimal** element $x_{0}$ with the property of $I_{x_{0}}$ being uncountable, such $x_{0}$ exists because in step 2 you discarded the case where every interval is countable and we are assuming the well order principle. Every element $y < x_{0}$ must satisfy $I_{y}$ being countable, otherwise $x_{0}$ wouldn't be the minimal element with the uncountable interval property. Now $I_{x_{0}}$ can't have a maximum precisely because of what you said.

Comment: @FZan That finally makes sense, thank you! By the way, it wouldn't be possible for x_0 to be the absolute minimal element of the set X correct? Because in that case I_x0 would simply be the empty set? 

I'd be happy to mark this as a correct answer if you're able to post it as one.